The specified database instance is currently in storage-full state. Please allocate more storage by modifying the DB instance
One of our slaveDb is showing as Storage-full state.
The initial Allocated size was 466 and Db.m4.large instance ( RDS)
Steps followed to increase the allocated space < 10% of the allocated space getting the following error
enter image description here
and > 10% of the allocated space getting the following error
enter image description here
Can some pls help over come and suggest the way to increase the space

Hi and welcome to Serverfault! Just a heads up that it's always better to put the text of the error(s) you have into your post rather than use screenshots, since that means people searching for that text will find them.
